# Can the software Keyboard toggle on the iOS Simulator always be toggled on?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-softkeyboard, kif

I'm testing an app using KIF and every time the test starts I have to manually toggle the software keyboard on and short of using a script to make it turn on is there a way to turn it on by default when the simulator opens?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not something that can be stuck on or off.  The behavior is *exactly* like a bluetooth keyboard connected to a physical device.  As there is no "always on" toggle for the real case, there is likewise no "always on" toggle in the simulator case.

The toggle/shortcut in the sim menu behaves just like tapping the eject key on a physical keyboard/device.

Answer (score 0):

The key for us was two-fold

1. Make sure "Connect Hardware Keyboard" is checked.  By default, when
   you click into a text field, this prevents the software keyboard from appearing.
2. Press Cmd+K to toggle the software keyboard.  If it wasn't appearing before, it will appear now.

Once you've done the above leave the sim in that state.  This state is the most easy to work with because you can type using the hardware keyboard and the software keyboard will appear so KIF will work.